# How does the browser cache the API response?

Tags: http, caching, browser, browser-cache, web-development-server

I'd like to achieve a deep knowledge about caching mechanism for website assets and even API requests. I read some articles and also searched about it in StackOverflow. There are some examples which show that, if you set for example: `max-age: 20;` browser will cache the RESTful API response for 20 seconds...

But the important question is that... If browser is able to cache the API response so, why we do have to use some libraries like `react-query` or using PWA to implement caching scenarios for web applications?

As far as I understand, if we use the browser cache and add `max-age` browser send request to server but server returns an empty response and makes browser to load from cache... but there is still an issue it would be that request to server to get the empty response.

But if we use something like `react-query` it even doesn't send that additional request to check cache with server and we can handle caching with zero request and it would a great trick to decrease server requests?

So, I am right? or this scenario is wrong and I couldn't learn it correct?

Thank you